# Why does the transaction exceed block gas limit?

Tags: transactions, accounts, gas, addresses, gas-limit

When I try sending ether to another account, I keep getting the message "*Exceeds block gas limit*".

I changed the gas amount from 5,000 to 100,000 but nothing else happened. Why does the transaction exceed the block gas limit?  How can I fix that?

Comment: You have to explain exactly what transaction you are talking about, also the question is specific to your case and does not help others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please paste the command you are trying to send the transaction with. A plain transaction needs `21000` gas per the protocol parameters. A block on the current main net goes up to `3 * PI million / 2`, or somewhat above 4 million gas.

If you get an error that the transaction exceeds the block gas limit, it usually means that you actually requested an enormous amount of gas to be attached to your transaction. Please double check your values.

Comment: So the gas limit is the maximum the contract method can spend. So would it be wise to set it approx. to the method gas usage in case the execution fails (and all the gas goes to the miner)?

Comment: i am trying to deploy smart contract via truffle having same issue of gas limit exceeds error ,. please have a look into it here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37455/error-exceeds-block-gas-limit